# Aceitar qualquer formato de Anexo

Tags: .net, vb.net, diretório

Tenho uma aplicação na qual é possível inserir anexos e depois fazer o download deles. Porém eu fiz de uma forma que a cada formato de arquivo que eu queira inserir como anexo, eu entro em um `For Each` desta forma

```
Private Sub grdAnexo_ItemCommand(ByVal source As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles grdAnexo.ItemCommand
        Dim idLote As Integer = Integer.Parse(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim diretorio As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Lote_Garantia\\"))
        Dim arquivo As FileInfo

        For Each item As FileInfo In diretorio.GetFiles("Lote_" + idLote.ToString + ".xls")
            arquivo = item
        Next

        For Each item As FileInfo In diretorio.GetFiles("Lote_" + idLote.ToString + ".xlsx")
            arquivo = item
        Next

        For Each item As FileInfo In diretorio.GetFiles("Lote_" + idLote.ToString + ".pdf")
            arquivo = item
        Next

        For Each item As FileInfo In diretorio.GetFiles("Lote_" + idLote.ToString + ".xml")
            arquivo = item
        Next

        For Each item As FileInfo In diretorio.GetFiles("Lote_" + idLote.ToString + ".jpg")
            arquivo = item
        Next

        For Each item As FileInfo In diretorio.GetFiles("Lote_" + idLote.ToString + ".jpeg")
            arquivo = item
        Next

        For Each item As FileInfo In diretorio.GetFiles("Lote_" + idLote.ToString + ".bmp")
            arquivo = item
        Next

        For Each item As FileInfo In diretorio.GetFiles("Lote_" + idLote.ToString + ".gif")
            arquivo = item
        Next

        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=""{0}""", arquivo.Name))
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", arquivo.Length.ToString())
        Response.WriteFile(arquivo.FullName)
        Response.End()

    End Sub
```

A minha duvida é, um meio de fazer com que o anexo aceite qualquer formato de arquivo sem ter que criar um novo `For Each` para cada um.
É possível ? Ou terei que continuar acrescentando um `for` para cada formato ?

Comment: Existe necessidade de usar `For Each` nesse código? Não é sempre 1 só arquivo com o nome seguindo o padrão `Lote_[ID].[EXTENSÃO]`?

Comment: @AndréRibeiro é o que eu havia observado. Do jeito que está não há esse necessidade, ele está operando em apenas um arquivo, o último que ele achar. É provável que ele está testando onde só tem um arquivo e então dá certo, mas se esta situação mudar, já não funciona mais. Eu **acho** que o *loop* é necessário para poder processar todos os arquivos disponíveis ou não é necessário porque é garantido que tenha só um arquivo (mas essas garantias são complicadas, elas só funcionam quando não há outros *bugs*).

Comment: Sim, é sempre um só arquivo. Porém, para cada operação em que é necessário incluir o lote de um pedido, os anexos são incluídos, cada um no seu formato(dependendo de qual o usuário escolher), sendo que todos armazenados na mesma pasta. Foi dessa forma que consegui identificar qual o nome do arquivo certo de acordo com o id_lote selecionado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, esse código não parece fazer sentido. Posso estar enganado porque não estou vendo o todo e não sei exatamente qual é seu objetivo mas eu acho que ele só funciona em situações específicas.

Se quer tratar qualquer tipo de arquivo, use um *wildcard*:

```
diretorio.GetFiles("Lote_" + idLote.ToString + ".*")
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetFilesWildCard.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Assim qualquer extensão é aceita.

Se realmente precisar especificar a lista de extensões possíveis, é aclaro que terá que adicionar cada uma individualmente. Se isto for preciso pode fazer apenas um *loop* filtrando o conteúdo.

Comment: Irei testar o wildcard. Pelo que me parece irá funcionar, já que o que preciso é só aceitar qualquer formato de arquivo

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente usando .* 
No começo só era permitido xls, xlsx e pdf. Com o tempo foram permitindo mais extensões. Para não gerar erro decidi aceitar todas as extensões.